# case insensitive array comparison in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-filter

I am comparing two arrays for matched items but I need to make them case insensitive.

here is the code: credit for this code to @PatrickRoberts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54950704/1541563)

```
const words = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3']
const texts = [
    {name: 'blah', description: 'word4'},
    {name: 'blah2', description: 'word1'},
    {name: 'blah3', description: 'word5'}
]

console.log(
  texts.some(
    ({ description }) => words.includes(description)
  )
)
```

I was able to get the second part to lower case by doing `words.includes(description.toLowerCase())` but I don't know how to handle the first part: `texts.some(({ description })` I should mention I have tried adding toLowerCase() to { description } like this: `{ description.toLowerCase() }` but this does not work

any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Switch either to the function `some` or function `find` or function `findIndex`.

```js
const words = ['Word1', 'word2', 'word3']
const texts = [{    name: 'blah',    description: 'word4'  },  {    name: 'blah2',    description: 'word1'  },  {    name: 'blah3',    description: 'word5'  }];

console.log(texts.some(({description}) => words.some((w) => w.toLowerCase() === description.toLowerCase())));
```

Comment: I will accept your answer as soon as stackoverflow lets me

Comment: Calling `description.toLowerCase()` in the inner arrow function is unnecessarily repeating a large amount of work that could be done in the outer arrow function instead.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible to change it during the destructuring process - [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49088061/10221765) explains why.

It's much easier to check by using `some` instead of `includes`:

```js
const words = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3']
const texts = [{
    name: 'blah',
    description: 'word4'
  },
  {
    name: 'blah2',
    description: 'word1'
  },
  {
    name: 'blah3',
    description: 'word5'
  }
]

console.log(
  texts.some(
    ({
      description
    }) => words.some(word => word.toLowerCase == description.toLowerCase())
  )
)
```

Comment: How is this different than [Ele's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54953587/1541563)?

Comment: Sorry @PatrickRoberts I didn't realise Ele had posted since I was on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to convert your objects into *strings*
2. Apply [`.toLowerCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) to the obtained strings so that everything (including all values) becomes lowercase
3. Convert back into an object or array using [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)
4. Apply the rest of the matching logic with `Array.some` and `Array.includes`

```js
const words = ['WORD1', 'WORD2', 'WORD3'];
const texts = [
    {name: 'blah', description: 'word4'},
    {name: 'blah2', description: 'word1'},
    {name: 'blah3', description: 'word5'}
];

const lower = x => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x).toLowerCase());
const [lowerWords, lowerTexts] = [words, texts].map(lower);

console.log(
  lowerTexts.some(
    ({ description }) => lowerWords.includes(description)
  )
)
```

Comment: yeah you're right @Ele . Thanks for catching that, I'll put an edit

Comment: This assumes that the `description` words are always lowercase as well. That isn't necessarily true.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts right, `description` may not be lowercase. I'll put an edit. Thanks for catching that